# UIView confusion

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

All , I am trying to figure out a UIView which gets bigger with this code :

```
 ColouredSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.84, green: 0.90, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
    ColouredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:50, width: 400, height: 30)
    self.view.addSubview(ColouredSquare)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        self.ColouredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 400, height: 180)
    })
```

I have added a button within the view. 
But the button draws before the UIView.

[image]

Comment: the `ColouredSquare` instance will be bigger, but it is impossible to tell you where that view is at in this tiny fragment of your view hierarchy. maybe you'd need to check the outlet connections between the view and code...

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something obvious here?

You set the frame:

```
ColouredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:50, width: 400, height: 30)
```

And then animate is, increasing the height to 180:

```
self.ColouredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 400, height: 180)
```